# Could not find stored procedure, however can execute it

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am new to SQL Server and created my very first stored procedure. It executes fine and I can locate it under 'Programmability', 'Stored Procedures' so I pop open a new query and type in the following statements:

```
use name_of_database
exec name_of_stored_procedure 'value'
```

However before executing the stored procedure, the name of the stored procedure is underlined in red noting it cannot be found, so I run the query:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES where ROUTINE_NAME = 'name_of_stored_procedure'
```

Nada. It returns nothing.

However if I go ahead and execute the stored procedure, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` query returned nothing, then I don't think the IntelliSense cache was your issue (or at least not your only issue). It sounds like you weren't in the context of the right database.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For SSMS you just need to clear the Intellisense cache (Ctrl + Shift + R).  Then the red squiggly line will disappear and Intellisense will help you out with that.

If you can view your Stored Proc under Programmability -> Stored Procedures in your object explorer, then you will be able to view it through your `select * from information_schema.routines ...` query.  Check your database context, as well as the rest of the query.  Take out the `where` clause and look through the whole result set.

Comment: Awesome. That worked like a charm. How often does SQL Server Management Studio clear its cache without me having to enter (CTRL + Shift + R)?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Good question.  I don't know the answer to that.  There is no option to set it in SSMS (that I know of).  It'll become a habit to just hit the necessary keystrokes.  Doesn't bother me personally.

Comment: Thanks dude. I was sitting here thinking what the hell am I doing wrong.

Comment: clear the Intellisense cache (Ctrl + Shift + R) works for me!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by simply using square brackets

```
EXEC [dbo].[procedureName]
```

Hope it helps someone later :)

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. I closed and opened Management Studio but it didn't work until I add the square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your procedure is in a schema other than `dbo`? You should always specify schema when creating and referencing objects. There are several reasons [as described here](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix). Essentially, when you don't specify the schema, you can have all sorts of confusing behavior depending on the default schema of the user who is creating or calling the procedure.

When checking for existence of objects you should also take schema into account.

Also you should check for procedures in `sys.procedures`. Some background info on [coding consistently here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views), since you can't always get the information you're after from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

Answer (score 1):

**In my case I solved the problem this way SIMPLY:**

1. Whenever I created the procedure I just execute the procedure on MSSQL Server Studio once. So I got the created procedure with the schema in the `db_name=>Programmibility=>Stored Procedure`.
2. Finally I called it from my C# code. And got solved!!!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you might just running the 2nd query against a different database, probably the master, try :

```
use 'name_of_database'
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES where ROUTINE_NAME = 'name_of_stored_procedure'
```

and then you should be able to see it

Comment: I did suspect that however and did run the same command as you suggested however it returns nothing.

Comment: That's interesting, would it be a typo of the name in the where clause?

Comment: Nope. As Shark indicated, all I needed to do was clear the cache.

Comment: Clear cache should solve the red underline problem but didn't realized that the table data also been cached, that's interesting...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and it was driving me nuts.

Couple of things I did to fix this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo.ProcedureName] (@Parameter, Datatype)
[dbo.ProcedureName] 'Parameter' OR EXEC [dbo.ProcedureName] 'Parameter'
```

OR

```
Go to Edit/IntelliSense/Refresh Local Cache **(cmd+shift+r)**
```